# ProgressBar not showing, android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Here is my code:

```
    automaticCountryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomeActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                setUpLocationPermission();
                return;

            }

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(gps.canGetLocation()));
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(gps.getLocation()));
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()));
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()));

            Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.this);

            try
            {
                myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), 1);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "unable");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(myList != null) {
                try {
                    String country = myList.get(0).getCountryName();
                    Log.d(TAG, country);
                    findCountryInArrayList(country);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Didn't manage to automatically detect location.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    });


}
```

I want that immediately after the view is clicked the progressbar will become visible. However, it donesn't become visable until all the code is finished, which is against the whole point. 
WHy is this not happening right at the beginning of the click? I have put progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) at the top, why is it only executed after all the code is done, which sometimes takes a few seconds.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are trying to do your work on the UI thread - the UI will not actually be updated at all until this method finishes.

Try changing up your call to this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    progressBar.post( new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            // long running code that has UI interactions
        }
    });
}
```

This will show the view immediately, and submit the runnable - long running task - to the message queue; this task will be run on a background thread that can still manipulate the UI, but will not cause it to hang.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That's exactly it.

Comment: But why is this so, if the first line of the code is to set the visibility? Only later I do the work on the UI thread?

Comment: The actual `onClick` method here is run in the thread that controls the UI. The actual render action will not happen until after this method returns. If the method takes 5s to complete, no screen rendering will happen for that 5s.